# Pentaho 7.1 report files stored in filesystem

Tags: linux, pentaho

We are moving form Pentaho 3.8 to Pentaho 7.1, quite a some upgrade. :)

However many things has changed, so I need some help every now and then. On 3.8 we have had folder on HDD where we have had all our reports stored. I am quite used to manage this folder through SVN, so I was trying to do it same way on Pentaho 7.1 but its not working.

At first I have switched `pentaho-server/pentaho-solutions/system/jackrabbit/repository.xml` back from postgres to FileSystem settings.
However it did not worked. I could not find folders created through web app on HDD.

Next step, I have tried to crerate folder on HDD, located in `pentaho-server/pentaho-solutions/`. added also `index.xml`vfile to recognize it and refreshed/restarted all I could find in pentaho, inculuding pentaho itself. Still can't see this folder in web app.

Now I am searching for possible location where to maintain those files, but there are so many possibilities, I could spend days working on it.

Can someone give me a hint or was doing something similar?

My system is Linux, and I use Community Edition of `pentaho-server`.

Answer (score 0):

Pentaho only uses Jackrabbit for storing the repository since version 5. There is no longer a physical copy in your hard drive.

Your best shot is using CBF2 and the import/export scripts to sync the jackrabbit repository and a folder on your drive you can then sync using SVN.

[CBF 2 blog post](http://pedroalves-bi.blogspot.co.uk/2016/04/cbf2-ultimate-collaboration-and-deploy.html)